# int array element not initialized to zero in C

Tags: c, arrays, initialization, int

I created an array of 10 elements in C inside of `main` and declared values for only some of the elements. When printing out the array I noticed that one of the elements, which was left untouched, was not initialized to zero. Instead, it was initialized to a different large value every time (i.e. `1491389216`). I then commented out all of my code and just left the array as I initially declared it.

When running the code, the first 8 elements of the array were initialized to zero, the 9th element in the array was being initialized to a large value (like `1491389216`) which changed every time, and the last element was consistently being initialized to the same non-zero number.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Post your code. [mcve]

Comment: You mean  in C  , that i edited ?

Answer (score 4):

Local (automatic) arrays are not initialized unless you explicitly initialize them.  Otherwise they contain whatever random data already occupies the memory.

If you want to zero out all of the elements when declaring the array, you can do this:

```
int arr[10] = {0};
```

Or:

```
int arr[10] = {};
```

Depending on your compiler (GCC allows this, unless you specify `-pedantic`).

Or, just use `memset()` instead:

```
int arr[10];
memset(arr, 0, sizeof(arr));
```

Similarly, memory allocated by `malloc()` — or extended by `realloc()` — is not initialized; use `calloc()` to zero-initialize such data:

```
int *arr = (int*) calloc(10, sizeof(int));
...
free(arr);
```

Comment: Using calloc function also satisfies i guess

Comment: *automatic* arrays aren't initialized. Static ones are. Fwiw.